# Can you turn Diesel/Petrol/Gasoline into electricity without an explosion?

Tags: power, generator, energy, alternator

Perhaps the title is a little click-baity, but having recently purchased a generator to power off-grid devices 24/7 (solar was a no-go due to its price/performance), I thought it was surprising that the highest energy-density source a common person can buy is diesel, and the seemingly only way to get the energy out of it is to run it through an engine to spin an alternator. Even really clean-burning and affordable fuel sources like propane can't just be burned and energy extracted from the heat - they also need to be run through a combustion engine (at thousands of rpm, in the upper 90dB(A)!) to convert the stored energy to electricity.

Is this really the best humanity can do? Are there no ways to convert a quiet little pilot flame from a propane tank into electricity with a similar ballpark efficiency to that of a combustion engine/alternator?

Comment: First, this question would fit much better on the general engineering SE site. Second, probably best to do more research on electrical power production. From combustion engines to steam turbines, efficient power production usually requires something to rotate quickly.

Comment: You make some assumptions, not sure if they're all correct since you clearly did not do much research otherwise you'd know about Fuel cells https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell Not sure if they're more efficient but at least they lack moving parts.

Comment: Have a look at the efficiency levels of thermoelectric generators - no currently we haven't anything which turns heat into electricity at 30% efficiency.

Comment: "Is this really the best humanity can do?" no, we have lots of ways to do it much more efficient, but are all hold back by oil company conspicacies. Seriously dude, if humanity could, we would be doing it already, duh.

Comment: I looked up fuel cells but they are not consumer-focused, with most modern ones involving Hydrogen gas. I will admit i should look more into it though since that wikipedia link talks about using Methanol.

Comment: burn stuff and use it to drive a Stirling engine, or a steam engine (turbine or reciprocating), so-called external combustion engines.

Comment: Arsenal - yeah there was a breakthrough in the field recently that showed they could get up to 40% efficiency and could be on sale in 5 years which sounds really exciting, however I was hoping there would be more efficient technologies that didn't use general heat but were optimised for the fuel source your using. I guess that is what a fuel cell is.
PlasmaHH - why make everything a conspiracy theory?

Comment: JJ, do a search on alcohol fuel cells.  I realized you only asked about hydrocarbons.  So I can't answer with "alcohol fuel cells" and provide links.  But I'm thinking you may be interested as, apparently from the ads, you don't have to be the military to buy these.

Comment: @J.J please try be specific and stay on topic. Thanks http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry laptop2d, you're going to have to specifically state what part of my question about electrical power generation is offtopic for electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can beat the 30% or so performance of petrol generators.

Sticking with reciprocating engines, a modern [marine diesel engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%A4rtsil%C3%A4-Sulzer_RTA96-C) can exceed 50% efficiency from thermal to mechanical power; combine that with a generator efficiency over 90% for one solution. They are quite large engines; one of the ways to improve thermal efficiency in an IC engine is keeping the hot gases away from the cool cylinder walls, which doesn't work in small cylinders.

But that quiet little pilot flame is indeed a better solution, and can exceed 60% thermal to electric efficiency. Just exploit it with the Brayton Cycle, and use the remaining heat in its exhaust gases to boil water, which you then use in a Rankine Cycle engine. Admittedly not so quiet, perhaps...

This is known as [combined cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_cycle) generation, and works well off a wide variety of fuels, from LPG through kerosene, and the Brayton Cycle has been demonstrated to [run from peat](https://wickiheats.wordpress.com/4-2/).

Comment: The modern marine diesel engine is a nice example for a slow rotating efficient engine, only 22 to 102 rpm. But a car engine would be too large for the car when rotating so slow. A single cylinder car engine would be possible and efficient but very unpopular.

Comment: Well you could probably park a SmartCar on one of these pistons. Scale the engine down following similarity (essentially, keep the linear speed of the piston constant, because the flame front speed doesn't change) and you get a few thousand RPM like a car's diesel engine. Obviously that loses thermal efficiency as the gas loses its heat to the cylinder walls. Try uncooled ceramic cylinders and pistons...

Comment: China has zillions of [**one lunger diesel 3 wheelers**](https://scontent-syd1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14188495_1141142219292605_1067188970706368358_o.jpg). Remarkably slow revving. Even at modest motorway speeds you can hear the individual cycles. At crawl up hill speeds they sound to be only a few hundred RPM.

Answer (score 3):

Stirling Engine.

External combustion Stirling Engine runs on the theoretically most efficient Carnot Cycle. Actual efficiencies can exceed 50% of Carnot and > 50% actual best case - so up there [tm] with Brian's marine diesels. Being external combustion there is NO explosive combustion so machines can be notionally very quiet.
Also very quiet in practice when desired - Swedes have molten salt 'fuelled' Stirling Engine driven submarines used to play super super quiet hide & go seek on their northern borders with their big brother neighbour.

The main problems with Stirling are achieving both mass and volume energy densities. Having modest temperature gas as a working fluid leds to a desire for higher RPM (which they are not good at), super high pressures and high specific heat gases. So you end up with 3000 psi ++ Helium and when that's not good enough, 3000++ psi Hydrogen. Murphy utterly loves Hydrogen under these conditions. It penetrates metal and embrittles thongs, and sealing is closer to impossible than most can stand. Also, to get decent Carnot efficiencies you want Thot 3 x Tcold or better so at around 300K cold you want 600C minimum and 900C is better and ... . Materials are run at or slightly beyond their practical limits.
If you don't mind low specific performance things are much easier. Large low power slow revving SE's have been built (search: Rice Husk Stirling) and new incarnations exist at present - made in the US of A even.

Long ago, about when they gave up on them, the great Philips Glolampen Fabriken (or spiritual descendants) opined that an excess of $50 billion development effort was required to really tame them and that WHEN success was achieved, payback through savings in fuel costs would be achieved in under 6 months. So far, much like fusion, a really successful Stirling engine always seems about 30 years away.

- Steam Engine
- Pulse Detonation engine - :-) :-) :-)

  As used in Aurora. [ :-) ]
- Fuel cells

Comment: I'm curious ... and OK a little sceptical ... if an actual Stirling engine has been constructed that beats the 39% reported by Hargreaves in "The Philips Stirling Engine" https://www.amazon.co.uk/Philips-Stirling-Engine-C-M-K-Hargreaves/dp/0444884637 ... links appreciated. But, at comparable efficiencies to IC, a good addition to the answers.

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic answer Russell, particularly for writing  it up after the accepted answer was accepted. I really appreciate that. Since posting this thread i've ordered a Stirling engine off eBay so hopefully i can learn a bit more about how they work practically. I also found a prototype diesel to hydrogen fuel cell system produced in the Neatherlands which claims to be more efficient and less polluting than a typical diesel generator, and certainly a lot quieter as there's no IC. Thank you (and Brian!) so much for answering my question :)

Comment: @Brian A few quick digs indicates better than 39% but nothing definitive. I believe I've seen > 50% overall - if/when anything surfaces (day to year away) I'll add more. For Tcold say 300k Carnot efficiency and ~= Thot in C is 50% @ 600K, ~= 325C, 66% at 900K, 625C, 75% at 1200k, 900C, 80% at 1500K, 1200C. [!!!!]. To get say 50% actual then % of Crnot needs to be 100% at 600K, 75% at 900k, 66% at 1200k. || So say target is 1200k/300K, Carnot = 75%, % of Carnot = 66%, Final = 50%. Arguably doable. Hard. Hot.